# MySQL обновление столбца. Ошибка

Tags: php, mysql

Такой код:

```
$new = $_POST['inputval'];
$sql = "UPDATE 'tableName' SET 'RowName'=$new WHERE 'ID'=1";
```

Ошибка при обновлении через AJAX:

```
Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''tableName' SET 'RowName'=Предзака�...' at line 1
```

Сам код брал из phpMyAdmin, такой запрос срабатывал отлично. переменная `$new` так же несёт в себе верную информацию. В чём ошибка?

Comment: Если в `$new` строка, то, наверное, надо её в кавычки же взять, типа `'RowName'='$new'`?

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, я так тоже пробовал, всё равно не то

Comment: Ошибка в том, что код ты взял откуда угодно, только не из phpMyAdmin. Тупо не осилил скопировать. Кавычки же эти  тебе не phpMyAdmin понаставил?

Answer (score 1):

Советую Вам использовать PDO для запросов. 
Файл `dbconnect.php` // подключаемся к БД

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=YourDB;host=YourHost;charset=utf8', 'UserName', 'UserPassword');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Файл запроса resp.php

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";
$new = $_POST['inputval'];
$sql = "UPDATE 'tableName' SET 'RowName' = :RowName WHERE 'ID'='1'"; // Запрос
$req = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$req->bindValue(':RowName', $new, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->execute(); // Выполняем запрос
?>
```

```
<?php
//Если нет желания использовать PDO, используйте следующий синтаксис
$new = $_POST['inputval'];
$sql = "UPDATE 'tableName' SET 'RowName'=".$new." WHERE 'ID'=1";
```

Comment: @Denis640Kb, По просьбе модератора поясняю для тех, кто не слишком опытен: менять синтаксис написания строк в РНР не имеет ни малейшего смысла. Что "foo $bar baz", что "foo ".$bar." baz" приведет к абсолютно иденичному результату. Поэтому следует воздержаться от таких советов, тем более что они довольно популярны у начинающих пользователей Stack Overflow на английском, и создают неверное представление о языке и его пользователях.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в кавычках. Надо было их убрать везде в названиях столбцов и добавить в переменную.

```
$sql = "UPDATE tableName
        SET RowName = '$new'
        WHERE ID = 1";
```

Comment: Рома, скажи, ты хочешь научиться писать нормальный код? Или тебе все равно, делаешь по принципу "и так сойдёт"?